# Run some DDL sql stored in couple of files

Tags: oracle

I have some files with some sql inside (mostly DDL) and I need just run them and see if there were any errors.

What would be the best way to do this ?

I'm using oracle 11.

Comment: I'd like to stop removing tags from your question titles. Please help me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

start sqlplus and run

```
@<path>/<filename>
```

You could also use something like sql developer, just open the files in that, select the server you want to run it on and hit F5 or press the "run script" button

Comment: Of course, you may wish to spool the output, and set echo on to see what statements, if any failed.  I'm fond of `whenever sqlerror exit rollback` so the script bombs immediately on first error.

Answer (score 1):

sqlplus -- [http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL*Plus_FAQ](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL%2aPlus_FAQ)